# How to validate username and password on Android using Java regex?

Tags: java, android, regex

I need the following regex pattern to validate a username and a password :

Username :

- Between 3 and 25 characters
- At least one character [a-zA-Z]
- Any character such as : 0-9, a-z, A-Z, _

i have ended up with this pattern but i can't figure out how to set the {3,25} (my tests are not validating it yet) :

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*{3,25}$`

Password :

```
     * ^                 # start-of-string
     * (?=.*[0-9])       # a digit must occur at least once
     * (?=.*[a-z])       # a lower case letter must occur at least once
     * (?=.*[A-Z])       # an upper case letter must occur at least once
     * (?=.*[a-zA-Z])    # any letter upper or lower case
     * (?=.*[@#$%^&+=])  # a special character must occur at least once
     * (?=\\S+$)          # no whitespace allowed in the entire string
     * .{6,}             # anything, at least six places though
     * $                 # end-of-string
     */
    private Pattern VALID_PASSWORD = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+!?=])(?=\\S+$).{6,}$");
```

I just need to change this pattern to allow special characters but i don't want to make them mandatory.

Comment: You could use the same mechanism like `(?=.{3,25}$)` Or match `\S{3,25}`

Comment: I need to allow numbers and i want to prevent the user from putting only numbers. So any letter must appear at least once upper or lower, and the whole thing must have between 3 and 25 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>***Username:***</sup>

Looking at your current patterns it seems like you can use the following pattern to validate your usernames:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w{3,25}$
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO0JwY/1).

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` - A positive lookahead, for any character other than newline zero or more times followed by a letter within `[a-zA-Z]` character class.
- `\w{3,25}` - Any character in the class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, three times up to a maximum of 25.
- `$` - End string ancor.

[image]

---

<sup>***Password:***</sup>

When you have checked for at least a single lower and a single upper case letter, that would defeat the purpose of checking any upper or lower case letter later down the line in your current pattern. Also, `.` which is any character would match special characters like the ones in your character class `[@#$%^&+!?=]`. When you don't want these to be mandatory, don't use them in a positive lookahead. Instead maybe try the following:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\S{6,}$
```

The only mandatory characters now are at least *one* digit, at least *one* lower case letter and at least *one* upper case letter. See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ssx9pL/8).

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?=.*\d)` - Positive lookahead for any character other than newline zero or more times followed by a digit.
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - Positive lookahead for any character other than newline zero or more times followed by a lower case letter.
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - Positive lookahead for any character other than newline zero or more times followed by a upper case letter.
- `\S{6,}` - Any non-whitespace character.
- `$` - End string ancor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. is it the \d making at least one digit mandatory ? 
It's indeed working fine thank you

Comment: @TommyD, that is correct. It's shorthand for `[0-9]`, whilst `\w` is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`